# Wipe clean all data from GAE datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have about 20GB of data in the datastore.
The builtin indexes (which I have no control over) have increased to ~200GB.

I backed up all the data to BigQuery and don't need it anymore.

I am trying to get out of the datastore, but I can't - datastore Admin console can't delete that many entities (bulk delete option uses map reduce, which fails on quota within an hour or so), and the cost of deleting each entity programatically is too expensive (> $1000 - many write operations because of the many indexes).
Meanwhile google charges me $50/month for storing the data I don't need :(

how do I: Close my datastore project (not the app engine project, just the datastore part of it), or just wipe out all the data?

Please help me get out of this!

Answer (score 3):

Wait until July 1, 2016. Then delete all entities.

Starting from July 1, 2016 the pricing is $0.02 per 100,000 deletes regardless of indexed properties.

Comment: Thanks Andrei!
Just looked it up - the new pricing is here: [App Engine Pricing](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/pricing)